# what is full screen mode

Tags: language-agnostic, window

I know you can fake full screen by expanding a window and eliminating the title bar , status bar , and other stuff, I'm not interested in this, I want to know about "real" full screen mode (I don't know how to call it else) , like in games.

what exactly is full screen mode?
what win-api should I use to achieve this?
can this be used to play movies in full screen ? I know windows media player uses a fake full screen because I can "cut" thru it and see the desktop (using regions win-api).
can I "cut" thru "real" full screen like I thru a window  (using regions win-api) ore is this directly writing to video memory and there is nothing "under" it?

Thanks!

Comment: You want to use DirectX.

Comment: so there is no win-api to do it?

Comment: DirectX *is* one of the Windows APIs. I mean, it's not in `user32.dll`, but that doesn't mean it's not a component of the extended Windows API. It's designed specifically for game programming, including a full-screen mode, as you describe.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make games on Windows in full-screen, the best option is **XNA**. This uses DirectX underneath, but hides a lot of the implementation details and plumbing to make it easy for the developer to start working on his game.

XNA is freely downloadable, and has good documentation.

XNA Game Studio 4.0 can be downloaded [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9ac86eca-206f-4274-97f2-ef6c8b1f478f).

Comment: You've not really answered the question here, you've simple thrown the OP onto a different technology claiming it to be the "dog's bollocks".  I personally don't like the rigid structure of XNA, but it does take care of a lot of things for you, so is easier for beginners. It is worth pointing out to the OP that the only way to request a window is through the win32 API, but you do not have to be using it directly, anything that does not look like win32 is simple abstracting it so you don't have to deal with how shit it is directly.

Answer (score 1):

...and you might want to support the "fake" fullscreen mode in addition to "real" fullscreen - it's very nice for those of us that run multi-monitor systems.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use DirectX, create window and call [ChangeDisplaySettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `CDS_FULLSCREEN` flag. OpenGL applications use this way to go fullscreen.

Comment: openGL does not have any notion of 'full screen'. window size is something is managed external to openGL and will give you a rendering context for openGL.

Answer (score 0):

As far as a user is concerned, full screen is just when a window takes up the entire screen such that they no longer see any window borders or other desktop stuff.

As you know, not all full screens are created equal.

'proper' full screen is where the program takes control of the screen. When a game uses this mode, it can change the resolution of you screen. If you have ever played an old game and existed to see your icons all messed up, this is; for the duration of playing the game, your desktop was at a lower resolution.

with 'borderless full screen' the program window is striped of any borders, the title bar and frame etc., and is just a rectangle of pure rendering. If you then set this rendering context to be the same size as your desktop, you get the effect of full screen.

Doing border-less is usually the more user friendly way these days, as it is easier to 'tab out' as the other programs are still graphically around. 'proper' full screen gives you full control of the hardware, so in theory you have more power for your program, but it means you have to wait for things to reinitialise when you tab out.

what you do with your rendering context is up to you, so yes, you can use it play videos. It would not matter if you are in 'proper' full screen or not, the rendering code would be the same.

As for cutting through proper full screen windows, I am not sure, but I think there would be nothing else to see, there is only your program.

as for what win-api, there is only one windows api, but I think you mean, what windowing library; as this is getting to be a long answer already, I shall just say it depends a lot on what you want from it.

Please feel free to leave comments if you need me to clarify or expand on any points.